# How to make a roslisp node load the shop2.asd?

Tags: ros, roslisp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I want to use the [SHOP2](http://www.cs.umd.edu/projects/shop/) from inside ROS.
Ideally, we can think of it completely as a black box.

So far, after *merely* creating a link (under ./lispturtles_pkg/asdf) to shop2.asd, the shop2 can be loaded manually from an REPL.

```
* (ros-load:load-system "lispturtles_pkg" "shop2")
```

How to make a roslisp node do that?

I have tried this:

```
(defun load-shop2 ()
  (with-ros-node ("mynode")
    (ros-load:load-system "lispturtles_pkg" "shop2")
      ))
```

It compiled successfully, but:

```
$ rosrun lispturtles_pkg load-shop2
 ...
Roslisp exiting due to condition: Error while trying to load definition for
                                  system shop2 from pathname
                                  /home/me/shop2-2.8.0/shop2.asd:
                                     Component "shop-asd" not found
[(ROSLISP EVENT-LOOP) INFO] 1346726523.266: Terminating ROS Node event loop
[(ROSLISP TOP) INFO] 1346726523.303: Shutdown complete
```

Any ideas why?
Should we adjust the shop2.asd? How? In which way?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42935/how-to-make-a-roslisp-node-load-the-shop2.asd-?/) by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2012-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess the problem is that you try to load shop2 using ros-load:load-system. For a first test, remove the link you created before and set up asdf2 to include the location you put shop2. Have a look at [the ASDF documentation](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html) for setup instructions. Now you should be able to load shop2 in the repl by:

```
(asdf:operate 'asdf:load-op :shop2)
```

Now, open your asdf file in lispturtles_pkg and add `shop2` to the system's dependencies.

While this solution should work, it's not perfect because it requires the user to manually install shop2 and set up asdf. A better solution would be to create a wrapper package that downloads and extracts shop2 into a ros package. For many examples, have a look at [cram_core](https://github.com/moesenle/cram_core.git), subdirectory 3rdparty.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0